# Service not triggered : The controller must return a response (null given)

Tags: facebook, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosfacebookbundle

Hi everyone and huge thanks for the help, 
I am trying to get FOSFacebook work, but it seems to be impossible until now. 
I tried a lot of configuration, and a lot of fix but nothing worked for me.

Here is my configuration :

**security.yml**

```
chain_provider:
    chain:
        providers: [fos_userbundle, fos_facebook_provider]
fos_userbundle:
    id: fos_user.user_provider.username
fos_facebook_provider:
      id: fos.facebook.custom_provider

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:  
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
    public:
          pattern:   ^/
          fos_facebook:
              app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/myApp/"
              server_url: "http://www.mywebsite.com"
              login_path: /facebook/login
              check_path: /facebook/check
              default_target_path: /
              provider: fos_facebook_provider
          anonymous: false
          logout:
              handlers: ["fos_facebook.logout_handler"]
```

**config.yml**

```
fos.facebook.custom_provider:
    class: Bundles\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
    arguments:
        facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
        userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
        validator: "@validator"
        container: "@service_container"
fos_facebook:
    file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
    alias:  facebook
    app_id: myid
    secret: mysecret
    cookie: true
    permissions: [email]
```

**routing.yml**

```
    _security_check:
        pattern:  /facebook/check

    _security_logout:
        pattern:  /logout
```

**Twig Template**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goLogIn(){
        window.location.href = "{{ path('_security_check') }}";
    }

    function onFbInit() {
        if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null ) {
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
                if (response.session || response.authResponse) {
                    setTimeout(goLogIn, 500);
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "{{ path('_security_logout') }}";
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
{{ facebook_initialize({'xfbml': true, 'fbAsyncInit': 'onFbInit();'}) }}
```

**UserController.php**

```
 * @Route("/facebook/check")
 */
 public function loginCheckFacebookAction(){

 }
```

And the provider and the modification to User class (as in the [Readme](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/README.md)).

But the problem is that the service not seemed to be called. Indeed, the method in the UserController must be a dummy method, and it is not like that here. 
The method is called and of course I get this error :

*LogicException: The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller? (uncaught exception).*

What is my error here ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove your UserController route/action `loginCheckFacebookAction`

Comment: The problem was solved here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/issues/186 ;)

Comment: Ok, then you should add an answer describing the solution.

Comment: The problem was located in the firewalls patterns. You cannot have two same patterns because only the first one will be executed. The right method here was to define only one firewall (with pattern /^) and set fos_facebook and form_login in it.

Comment: so whts the final solution ? Can you paste working security configurations ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct answer for this old question is, but I ran into this same problem and my issue was I was using the wrong path for the firewalls:default:pattern Setting it to something like ^/ make the authentication always enabled, then define access rules in the access_control block in security.yml.